# How to create a record (in ember.js) with belongsTo relationship and persist it in django via tastypie?

Tags: jquery, json, django, ember.js, tastypie

So I am doing a chat application (frontend in ember.js and backend in django) which of course has to send messages.

My message model in ember.js looks like this:

```
Messages.Message = DS.Model.extend({
    body: attr('string'),
    user: DS.belongsTo('user'),
    time: attr('date'),
    recipient: DS.belongsTo('recipient'),
});
```

I tried to create and persist new message using code from this example: http://emberjs.com/guides/models/creating-and-deleting-records/

so my saveMessage action in controller looks like this:

```
var store = this.store;

var message = store.createRecord('message', {
    body: 'Lorem ipsum'
});

store.find('recipient', 2).then(function(recipient) {
    message.set('recipient', recipient);
});

message.save();
```

but the generated JSON`s attribute 'recipient' is null, so server returns error 500 because this field cannot by blank.

JSON should looks like:

```
{'body': 'loremipsum', 'recipient': {'username','some name'}, 'time': null, 'user': null}
```

Do you have an idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find` is asynchronous, and returns a promise.  That means the anonymous function passed to the `then` can likely be executed after you've called `save`.  Move the save inside the then so that the recipient has been attached before saving.

```
var store = this.store;

var message = store.createRecord('message', {
    body: 'Lorem ipsum'
});

store.find('recipient', 2).then(function(recipient) {
    message.set('recipient', recipient);
    message.save();
});
```